# Which mailing address to use for disputing a California Franchise Tax Board 5818 Notice?

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, california

I just got an FTB 5818 Notice saying that I don't have Health Insurance.

I am planning to dispute it by sending in my 1095-B.

Question: Which mailing address should I be using:

1. Franchise Tax Board
   PO Box 942840
   Sacramento CA 94240-0001

or

2. Franchise Tax Board
   PO Box 942867
   Sacramento CA 94267-0001

Comment: what did the paperwork they sent you say?

Comment: The wording on the notice is pretty vague.  It says:  "If you disagree with our notice, gather the following before contacting us.".  The only address I see on the notice is on the letterhead.

Comment: Do you have a MyFTB account? You can take care of this online if so (upload evidence, etc.). Even if no account, check instructions at https://www.ftb.ca.gov/help/letters/notice-of-tax-return-change.html.

Answer (score 1):

I did call FTB to confirm.  The mailing address to contact them is the one listed on the upper left-hand corner of the notice itself.  Reporting back so that others will know where to go when faced with a similar situation.

Thanks all for your replies.